# WIPO search missing form data POST message

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize, mechanize-python

i am trying to search trough the WIPO brand register with python, but if i am checking the formdata which got send to the server i don't really understand what this is.

Form Data:

[image: formdata]

This is the formdata if i am searching for "Lumunu", where come these characters from?

Wipo URL: https://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/

Answer (score 0):

I started in the same way as you and found no solution using the POST method. After much research on Google almost without success I noticed that it is possible to make queries in JSON format directly on the URL. For example, if I am searching for the "alpina" brand, specifying Costa Rica as "country of origin" "CR", Holder Country Colombia "CO", and Goods/Services "leche" (milk in Spanish) you could get the URL like this:

```
import requests
url_base = 'http://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/?q='

query = {"searches": [
    {"te":"alpina","fi":"BRAND"},
    {'te': 'CR', "fi": 'OO'},
    {'te': 'CO', "fi": 'HOLC'},
    {"te": "leche", "fi": "GS"}
]}

url = url_base + str(query).replace(" ", "").replace("'", "\"")
print(url)

response = requests.get(URL)
print(response.status_code)

response.content
```

I have not been able to find documentation, what I have achieved has been trial and error, but it works.